# Helper class in ABAP to convert to Odata primitive types

Tags: json, odata, abap

Is there any helper class in ABAP which I could use to convert ABAP data type of  Date time format to that of Odata type ? I am creating a JSON payload natively in ABAP to post to a http REST API and the service expects the date to be in edm.datetimeoffset format . I was wondering if there is way to convert a date time stamp to that format so I could convert and send it out as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely all the OData code is part of SAP Netweaver Gateway, which may or may not be installed on your system. I don't think it should be a problem to construct the correct value.

The format is defined in the OData spec [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt)

```
dateTimeOffsetValue = year "-" month "-" day "T" hour ":" minute [ ":" second [ "." fractionalSeconds ] ] ( "Z" / sign hour ":" minute )
```

Using this pattern you could create the following string template expression.

```
date_time = |{ date DATE = ISO }T{ time TIME = ISO }Z|.
```

There's an example in the JSON format page [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940629).